# SPSS Set Page breaks in Syntax

Tags: spss

Is it possible to set page breaks using syntax for the Output viewer? I am looking for ways to programmatically control the content in the output window; everything seems to be done by pointing and clicking.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extensive scripting interface for working with the Viewer using either Python or Basic.  The api item.SetPageBreak(True) will do this.

But the easiest way to do this is to use the SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT extension command, which allows you to specify the object types where you want to insert a break and does this for you.
You can get it from SPSS Developer Central (www.spss.com/devcentral).

Comment: Jon, thanks for the tip.  I may be able to make that work, but where can I find documentation on how to manipulate elements in the Viewer window; I think I am overlooking it? I am hoping to get some help on deleting, renaming, setting page breaks, etc. After trying some other approaches, I think I may be able to make the Viewer work for my needs with scripting.

Answer (score 2):

A title e.g. `TITLE "my title".` or subtitle will produce a pagebrake (At least if you export to PDF). Just leave the (sub)title empty (`TITLE "".`) you don't want any title printed.

Answer (score 1):

Scripting doc is installed with the Python plugin, or you can use the help in the Basic scripting editor.